# Wraping the mouse cursor on desktop edges

Tags: windows, winapi, mouse

I would like to wrap the mouse cursor on desktop edges, (when my app is run and has focus, but it may be also windowed thus less area then screen)

when it goes to left adge i would want go jump on right when it goes down i want to jump it from up

Is there an easy way to obtain this effect?

(winapi functions only)
tnx

Comment: You need SetWindowsHookEx().  And a good uninstaller.

Comment: Your users will despise you with incredible passion and they will remove your software with extreme prejudice